# Loop em $_POST para salvar dados em um arquivo .CSV

Tags: php, html

Olá,

Estou com uma dúvida já faz dois dias, estou tentando de tudo e ainda não consegui, se alguem puder me ajudar!!

Fiz um formulário em HTML e PHP, onde eu preencho o formulário e após dar submit eu gero um arquivo .csv com os dados preenchidos, até ai tudo bem.. O problema em si, é que eu fiz um script JS para clonar os campos do formulário, para enviar mais de 1 pedido, e eu não estou conseguindo pegar os valores dos formulários que foram clonados e jogar dentro do arquivo csv.

Segue o código..

```
    <?php
$error = '';
$projeto = '';
$quantidade = '';
$altura = '';
$largura = '';
$material = '';
$descricao = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
    return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
        if(empty($_POST["projeto"]))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Descreva o Projeto</label></p>';
    }
        else
        {
            $projeto = clean_text($_POST["projeto"]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["quantidade"]))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Informe a Quantidade</label></p>';
    }
        else
        {
            $quantidade = clean_text($_POST["quantidade"][0]);
            if(!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]*$/",$quantidade))
            {
                $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">É Permitido Apenas Números e Espaços</label></p>';
        }
    }

    if(empty($_POST["altura"]))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Informe a Altura</label></p>';
    }
        else
        {
            $altura = clean_text($_POST["altura"][0]);
            if(!preg_match("/^[0-9 (,)]*$/",$altura))
            {
                $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">É Permitido Apenas Números e Espaços</label></p>';
        }
    }

    if(empty($_POST["largura"]))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Informe a Largura</label></p>';
    }
        else
        {
            $largura = clean_text($_POST["largura"][0]);
            if(!preg_match("/^[0-9 (,)]*$/",$largura))
            {
                $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">É Permitido Apenas Números e Espaços</label></p>';
        }
    }

    if(empty($_POST["material"]))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Selecione o Material</label></p>';
    }
        else
        {
            $material = clean_text($_POST["material"][0]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["descricao"]))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Informe a Descrição</label></p>';
    }
        else
        {
            $descricao = clean_text($_POST["descricao"][0]);
    }

    if($error == '')
    {
        $form_data = array(
            "$projeto\n",
            "\n \nQuantidade; Largura; Altura; Material; Descricao\n $quantidade[0]; $largura[0]; $altura[0]; $material[0]; $descricao[0]\n"
        );

        $file_open = fopen("$quantidade;".date("d-m-y;h-i-s").".csv", "a");

        print_r($_POST);

        fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
        $error = '<label class="text-success">Pedido Enviado com Sucesso!</label>';
        $projeto = '';
        $quantidade = '';
        $altura = '';
        $largura = '';
        $material = '';
        $descricao = '';
    }

    //header('Location: /planilha/formulario.php');
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste CSV FILE</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                  var elm_html = $('#clone-form').html();

                  $(document).on('click', '.clone', function(e){
                      e.preventDefault();
                      var i = $('.cadastroPecas').length;    
                      var elementos = elm_html.replace(/\[[0\]]\]/g, '['+i+++']');
                      $('#clone-form').append(elementos);
                  });
                  $("#clone-form").on('click', '.delete-clone', function() {
                   $(this).parent().remove();
                });
              });
        </script>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
        </nav>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br />
        <div id="conteudo" class="container">
            <h3 align="center">Peças a Serem Cortadas</h3>
            <br />
            <?php echo $error; ?>
            <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <form method="post">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-14">
                                <input type="text" name="projeto" class="form-control" placeholder="Descrição do Projeto:" />
                        </div>                      
                        <div class="row engloba" id="clone-form">
                            <div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" name="quantidade[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade:" />
                                </div>                              
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" name="largura[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Largura:" />
                                </div>                          
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" name="altura[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Altura:" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <select name="material[]" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Material:</option>
                                        <option value="1 - MDF Branco 18mm">1 - MDF Branco 18mm</option>
                                        <option value="2 - MDF Wengue 15mm">2 - MDF Wengue 15mm</option>
                                        <option value="3 - MDF Carvalho 18mm">3 - MDF Carvalho 18mm</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>              
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <input type="text" name="descricao[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Descrição:" />
                                </div>

                                    <button type="button" class="clone btn btn-outlined btn-success">+</button>                         
                                    <button type="button" class="delete-clone btn btn-outlined btn-danger">-</button>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group" align="center">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Calcular</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: quando vc da o submit, os campos com `name="valor[]"` são passados como `array()` para o `PHP`, teria, por exemplo, `$_POST['descricao']` como um `array()`, vc teria que separar por chaves, pois cada chave corresposde a sua respectivo `<input>`

Answer (score 0):

```
  $form_data = array(
                "$projeto\n",
                "\n \nQuantidade; Largura; Altura; Material; Descricao\n"
            );

            for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['quantidade']); $i++) {
                $linha = $_POST['quantidade'][$i].";". $_POST['largura'][$i].";". $_POST['altura'][$i].";". $_POST['material'][$i].";". $_POST['descricao'][$i]."\n";
                array_push($form_data, $linha);  
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Tomei a liberdade e fiz algumas alterações no código:

```
$error=$projeto=$quantidade=$altura=$largura=$material=$descricao='';
$sum_quantidade=0;//variavel da soma da quantidade

function clean_text($string){
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
    return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(empty($_POST["projeto"])){
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Descreva o Projeto</label></p>';
    }else{
        $projeto = clean_text($_POST["projeto"]);
    }
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['quantidade']);$i++){
        if(empty($_POST["quantidade"])){
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Informe a Quantidade</label></p>';
        }else{
            $quantidade[$i] = clean_text($_POST["quantidade"][$i]);
            if(!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]*$/",$quantidade[$i])){
                $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">É Permitido Apenas Números e Espaços</label></p>';
            }
        }

        if(empty($_POST["altura"])){
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Informe a Altura</label></p>';
        }else{
            $altura[$i] = clean_text($_POST["altura"][$i]);
            if(!preg_match("/^[0-9 (,)]*$/",$altura[$i])){
                $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">É Permitido Apenas Números e Espaços</label></p>';
            }
        }

        if(empty($_POST["largura"])){
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Informe a Largura</label></p>';
        }else{
            $largura[$i] = clean_text($_POST["largura"][$i]);
            if(!preg_match("/^[0-9 (,)]*$/",$largura[$i])){
                $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">É Permitido Apenas Números e Espaços</label></p>';
            }
        }

        if(empty($_POST["material"])){
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Selecione o Material</label></p>';
        }else{
            $material[$i] = clean_text($_POST["material"][$i]);
        }

        if(empty($_POST["descricao"])){
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Informe a Descrição</label></p>';
        }else{
            $descricao[$i] = clean_text($_POST["descricao"][$i]);
        }

        $form_projeto[]=array(" $quantidade[$i]; $largura[$i]; $altura[$i]; $material[$i]; $descricao[$i]\n");//cria um arrai para cada linha dos valores definidos nos imputs HTML
        $sum_quantidade+=intval($quantidade[$i]);//soma da quantidade de produtos, usada no nome do arquivo .csv
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        $form_data = array(
            "$projeto\n",
            "\n \nQuantidade; Largura; Altura; Material; Descricao\n"
        );
        $file_open = fopen("$sum_quantidade;".date("d-m-y;h-i-s").".csv", "a");
        fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
        foreach ($form_projeto as $key=>$value) {
            fputcsv($file_open, $value);
        }
        fclose($file_open);
        $error = '<label class="text-success">Pedido Enviado com Sucesso!</label>';
    }
    //header('Location: /planilha/formulario.php');
}
```